# Why would Firefox put anything in the clipboard on exit?

Tags: firefox, clipboard, exit

I have an Autohotkey script that gets triggered whenever image data (not text or other data types) is copied to the clipboard.

When I close Firefox, the script gets triggered.  This doesn't make any sense to me.  Does anybody have an explanation?

Extra info:  As for the purpose of the script itself, it is designed to work with the Hypersnap software.  You see,  I have Hypersnap save each screenshot I take.  However, it does not offer the naming scheme I want.  Therefore, I use Autohotkey to rename the image after it is saved.  I have tried many things, and so far the only way I can get Autohotkey to detect when a new screenshot is taken is by setting Hypersnap to put a copy of the image in the clipboard and have Autohotkey detect that.  When this new image data is detected in the clipboard, the script searches the Hypersnap save folder and renames the new screenshot image.

**EDIT:**
It turns out that this question is not even valid as it is stated, because I have discovered that the clipboard contents do not change when closing Firefox, even when the AHK script is triggered as described.  The problem lies elsewhere, perhaps with the script itself.  I could probably delete this question, but Karan's suggestion to use Greenshot may prove very useful in an indirect way, and I believe it may help others as well.

Comment: Firefox uses screenshots of what you were doing last, to present you with a nifty thumbnail menu of the most recent and most often visited websites.  It can present you with this menu page when you open a new tab.

Comment: @BonGart: Yes, but surely it doesn't place those screenshots on the clipboard?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you start Firefox in safe mode and then close it? If not then perhaps an add-on is to blame.

Comment: @BonGart, in addition to what Karan said, I also don't see why it would be placing the screenshots when you exit the browser.

Comment: @Karan, to be honest, I actually can't seem to reproduce it at all, whether in safe mode or not.  It doesn't happen all of the time, and when I posted I wasn't really considering that.  I just saw it happen, remembered it has happened multiple times before, and decided to ask about it.  I don't close Firefox often, though...

Comment: I know my installs of Firefox don't put anything on the clipboard when I close them, but since Firefox was performing this screenshot/thumbnail dealio, I thought it might be a place to look.  That's why it was just a comment, as opposed to an answer.  Have you left the Clipboard open to see exactly what is being put there?

Comment: I agree with @BonGart, would help if next time this happens you can save what's been placed on the clipboard. Also, just to clarify in case it wasn't clear,  by safe mode in my comment above I meant FF's own, not Windows'.

Comment: @Karan, I knew what you meant.  Also I don't have a clipboard viewer at the moment.  I'll have to obtain one (it isn't included in Windows 7)

Comment: Using a 3rd party clipboard viewer, I watched as I closed Firefox.  As it did before, it triggered the snapshot renaming script.  However, the clipboard contents did not change at all (I had some text in there).  Apparently something else is causing the script to fire when I close Firefox.  I guess my question is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the discussion above, perhaps switching to [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org) can be an option. It has advanced file naming syntax you can use which means the malfunctioning AHK script won't even be required:

[image: 1]

Comment: Free, open source, intuitive, and lightweight?  This seems to be pretty amazing.  I've used Hypersnap for so long, though... it'd feel weird switching to something else.  Disloyal, even.  I'm definitely going to give it a try, though.  Thanks for this!  While it doesn't solve the mystery and even though my question isn't even really valid any more, this is certainly helpful enough to be accepted as an answer.

Comment: After playing with Greenshot for a little bit, I can certainly say it is nice, but it isn't quite as feature rich as Hypersnap.  However, switching over would be give and take. Each has some helpful features that the other does not seem to have.  In my line of web design work, I often like to very quickly see what the color of something is, and when using Hypersnap I can start a screen capture and it will tell me the color (in hex or RGB) under my cursor.  I use that feature a LOT...

Comment: Why not use a dedicated colour picker tool for that instead of a screenshot utility? Anyway, I'm sure you'll figure out whatever works best for your workflow...

Comment: I have considered that option.  However there are other differences as well.  The color thing was just an example.  I'll have to poke around more and find out what I can do.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.  Nice to know about Greenshot.